# iPhone Application crashes, when I load a HTML string(huge data) onto WebView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a Webview where I try to post huge amount of data say around 20 MB which includes images. I have collected everything into a string and passed that particular string to webview. The problem arises when the string size increases. It works fine if the size of the string is less.

I did check by debugging, that the control reaches the WebViewDidFinishLoading delegate method. The fully loaded string gets uploaded , but the application gets crashed within couple of seconds. What might be the reason? Please help me out! I have been banging ma head.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that you are using up too much memory. iOS kills such apps. Apart from loading such a huge HTML, `UIWebView` itself has memory issues. Its been accused of taking too much memory as it caches data (images etc.)

Maybe emptying the cache could help. In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` try this -

```
 NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
 [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
 [sharedCache release];
```

Also when you receive memory warning do this -

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
}
```

You are just purging cache to free up memory.

If this too is not working then i suggest you figure out ways to split your HTML into multiple pages or some other way to present data.

Comment: how one can split single page HTML into multipage html and load it in webview, if he wants to show that HTML as a single page?

Answer (score 1):

This issue I faced in one of my applications.  Please check following link for solution. I hope it works well.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56424953/8259188

Answer (score 0):

Use Instruments to profile your app. There's a good chance that you're simply running out of memory -- 20MB is quite a bit for an iOS app, and if you're building that string up from parts you may be copying a lot of smaller strings. It would be useful to know how much memory your app is using at the point when it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing it at startup of the application?  If so, it could be taking to long for the app to launch and is causing the watch dog timer to kill the app.