# How to display heavy data in webview in swift 4

Tags: html, ios, swift

In one of my applications, I have to show html content in a web view which comes from web service response. If the html data is smaller then it will display in webview. But when html content is very heavy that time at the time of display in web view app kills.

One thing I did just only to check, I create one html file which contains heavy data and saved in project. I display this file in webview successfully. Then why webview not show heavy html data.

I used this method to show html string into the webview.

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString , baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: If your app crashes then include error/stack trace in your question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson actually app is killed not crashes because of memory issue. and there is no stack provided in log. one thing I observed when I try to run application on simulator it works fine because of simulator having large memory.

Comment: Please check 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/77239

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you load your html file in Safari on your phone?

Comment: Have you checked leaks in developer tools?

Answer (score 2):

i had this type of issue. I searched a lot on this issue. This issue raised because memory. After searching a lot and debugging , i got the actual reason of this issue.

When Html content too large and when we are trying to load this html content into uiwebview and also increasing uiwebview height wrt to content size of uiwebview, that time memory issue raised.

First Solution :
 If you have static html content then you can store this in one .html extension file within project and display this file into uiwebview. This way you can't raised any issue and uiwebview height also increases wrt to content size of uiwebview.

Second Solution:
If your uiwebview height increases drastically then do one thing set height of uiwebview in that case at certain level. Which resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. This works for me. I already spent much more time to solve this issue but not able to trace issue.